# UI-Router Child doesn't replace template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have `<div ui-view>` inside my `index.html` file. Here are my 5 states:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('front', {
     url: '^',
     templateUrl: 'templates/front.html'
  })
  .state('member', {
     url: '/member',
     templateUrl: 'templates/member.html'
  })
  .state('cpanel', {
     url: '^/cpanel',
     templateUrl: 'templates/cpanel.html'
  })
  .state('cpanel.users', {
     url: '/users',
     templateUrl: 'templates/users.html'
  })
  .state('cpanel.users.edit', {
     url: '/:id',
     templateUrl: 'templates/users.edit.html'
  })
```

I only want to focus on the `/cpanel` portion:

**cpanel.html**

```
<!-- Header -->
<!-- Common divs -->
<div ui-view></div>
```

**users.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="edit()">
   <div ng-bind="user.name"></div>
   ...
</div>
```

When I redirect to the `cpanel/users/1` for example, I still see `users.html` page, and the content from `users.edit.html` doesn't replace the old list from `users.html`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*cpanel.users.edit* is a child scope of *cpanel.users* but *templates/users.html* has no ui-view so nothing will show. Also *cpanel.users.edit* cannot replace *cpanel.users* because it is it's child scope.

One solution would be to make *cpanel.users* abstact with template:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

and add *cpanel.users.list* to actually list the users.